# Center one Column in a Tablelayout and align the other to the right and left

Tags: android, center, tablelayout, multiple-columns

I just started with some Android Programming and have a really hard time with making layouts. I want to make the following tablelayout and I want to have the middle TextView (textView3) centered horizontally of the Page and the other two TextViews should be to the left and right of the centered column. If one of the values in the left or right TextView generates a line break the other two TextViews should also be centered vertically.

I hope someone understands my problem.
Greetz

```
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </TableRow>
```

Comment: Setgravity to center.

Comment: like this   android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="right" for your textviews

Comment: If I set the TableRow to android:gravity="center_horizontal" the whole row will be centered, which is logical. If I set the textView3 to android:gravity="center_horizontal" nothing happens at all. I tried all different kinds of android:gravity and android:layout_gravity but cant get it to work.

Comment: try this android:layout_gravity="left" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="right"

Comment: or you can use android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" and specify others like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after some more research I got it working by setting the `android:layout_width="0dip"` for each TextView. The Problem was, that `android:layout_weight` depends on the actual width of the TextViews, so "wrap_content" was not working.

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this please:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Okay, we are getting closer but thats still not the way I want it to be. Here you can see the output: http://picload.org/image/oagwldd/table.jpg The "-" should be centered of the whole Page and the right TextView would need to create a line break.

Comment: Ok, remove `android:gravity="right"` and `android:gravity="center"` from my code

Comment: This still does not put the middle TextView with "-" into the center of the Page. I really dont get why this is not working at all. It seems like Android says "Haha, look if I move that TextView a bit to the left I can fit the next Text into the same row without a line break and this for I ignore all statments!".